# How to make a Subview pop-up from an action in UITableviewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to pop-up a subview pop-up from one of the actions performed by a button placedon a tableview controller.

I initially added a sub-view(initally hidden below the screen) and later want to animate it to
animate and pop-up.
Here is the code for the button action

```
-(IBAction) finalShareVerse: (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"finalShare Button");
    UIView *tempView;
    CGRect tmpFrame;
    tempView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 90)] 
         autorelease];
    [tempView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [tempView setAlpha:.87];
    [self.view addSubview:tempView];

    tmpFrame = tempView.frame;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.75];
    tmpFrame.origin.y=390;
    self.view.frame=tmpFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The problem is that now the parent controller gets animated and popped down instead of 
the subview to be popped up.
Is there a way to specify the animation to trigger on only the sub view.

I am new to iPhone app dev.. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is the line:

```
self.view.frame=tmpFrame;
```

You are applying the change of position to the view rather than the tmpView

Comment: Thanx for this ... The problem was that tempView is a local variable to the function..
 Once I made it an instance variable it worked fine ... thnx again.